# Mongo transactions Manager bean presence alters behaviour of save() for JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I have a use case to use Mongo transactions. For enabling transactions i followed the [mongo transaction document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.transactions) 
In my application I have MySql DB connections as well.

Upon creating the mongo transaction bean, the JPA repositories save() method is not persisting data.

The JPA repositories save method works well, if I comment out MongoTransactionManager bean:

```
public class MongoTransactionConfiguration  extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties props;

/*    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }*/

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(props.getUri()));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return props.getDatabase();
    }
}
```

The sample code is available in [github](https://github.com/KencyK/demo)
In this example I'm connecting to local host mysql, and as part of @PostConstruct of Application class, will try to populate a table.

The table gets populated when mongo transaction bean does not exists.
But when the MongoTransactionBean exists nothing gets populated.

I expect to have MongoTransactions enabled and proper functioning of mysql save(). Could someone help me figure out how to overcome this issue?

Comment: have you tried qualifiers to distinguish between the transaction managers to use? See [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) for more details.

Comment: Yes after using qualifiers it had worked. I think JPA uses transactionManager as its default. Thanks @ChristophStrobl !